# k3s ingress to my app's service routing using daemonset not working

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, k3s

I have k3s cluster working pretty well with Grafana monitoring and traefik/klipper-lb. However my own app Ingress does not work.

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-esp
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test-esp.nip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: test-esp
          servicePort: http
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-esp
  name: test-esp
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 22000
    targetPort: 22000
  selector:
    app: test-esp
```

**daemonset.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-esp
  name: test-esp
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-esp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-esp
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: test-esp
        image: <gitlab image pull url>
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: test-esp-config
        ports:
        - containerPort: 22000
        command: ["/home/scripts/entrypoint.sh"]
        args: ["1"]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources: {}
```

** 3 Nodes in K3s have DaemonSet Pods running **

```
> kubectl get po -n myapp
NAME                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
test-esp-9cwzp   1/1     Running   0          4m3s
test-esp-qjk5n   1/1     Running   0          4m3s
test-esp-j8nnk   1/1     Running   0          4m3s
```

** curl on individual nodes work **

```
masternode-1> curl -XGET http://masterip:22000  
<long html page>
```

** curl from ingress times out **

```
mylocal> curl -XGET http://test-esp.nip.io
gateway timeout
```

** ping/telnet to test-esp.nip.io finds the ip works well **

Any experts out there, is this something do with iptables ?